# Wp menu add page link as custom empty link

Tags: menus, admin-menu, add-menu-page

i've a problem with wp menu, in the admin panel when i try to add a new page link to menu it creates a custom empty link instead,  everything was working fine until i installed qtransalte X, when i clicked savemenu every menu links were emptied and converted to custom links.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

finally i found where does the issue come from, it was a custom post metas that causing this problem, i don't know why but when i removed them, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you had is based on the custom post meta collision with [qtransalte X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/).